# Delete row from tableview after audioplayer finish

Tags: ios, xcode

I need some help at this problem:

**Delete a row from a `UITableView` after the audio of that row has finished playing.**

I have a UITableView with some cells. Every cell have a unique sound. If you select a row the audio of the cell plays.

I want that the row that is selected will be deleted after the audio is finished.

Here you can see when the audio finished with playing.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                message:@"Player finish." 
                                                delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the row you want deleted into an instance variable (for example `_rowToDelete`) and then use the `[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation]` method to remove the row from the table view.

You must ensure it's also removed from your datasource **before** removing it from the tableview.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
                       successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self.myTableData removeObjectAtIndex:_rowToDelete];
    NSArray *indexPaths = @[ [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:_rowToDelete] ];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply delete the entry from your datasource array and do a

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` just remove the data from the data source of `UITableView` and reload the tableView.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all use observer pattern i.e NSObserver and add object of
>   audio player in observer. It will helps you to track when audio player
>   stops. After that you can delete the row with the help of @trojanfoe
>   answer.